# Problem trying to call mmap in 32-bit i386 assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls, mmap

My goal is to have a moemory page which I can set to be executable,so that I could put actual machine code in it and execute from the assembly, just like I would do in C. But got stuck with the function call. According to https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=x86

mmap function can be called setting the registers accordingly. Here is my assembly code

```
 mov ebx, 0      ;address
 mov ecx, 4028   ;size
 mov edx, 0x7    ;protection: PROT_EXEC | PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ
 mov esi, 0x22   ;flags: MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE
 mov edi, -1     ;fd: according to man page shoud be set to -1
 mov ebp, 0      ;offset: according to man page shoud be set to zero
 mov eax, 0x5a
 int 0x80
```

Since [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) doesn't say the value of MAP_ANONYMOUS, I had to search it, I don't know if [this one](https://sites.uclouvain.be/SystInfo/usr/include/bits/mman.h.html) it's correct. At the end, however, eax is set to -14. Which I think is an error. 
 Am I doing something wrong with the registers? Does the return value of mmap really go to eax? What is the problem? I am using nasm for compiling the assembly. Here's how I'm doing it

```
nasm -g -f elf32 test1.asm
ld -m elf_i386 test1.o -o output
```

Comment: I suppose the numbers for i386 could be different.

Comment: The old `mmap` system call takes an argument struct. You likely want `mmap2` instead which is number `192`. PS: use `strace` to trace system calls.

Comment: So it worked just fine with mmap2, Thank you @Jester